# Include file name to be part of xml to csv conversion in Python

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I am trying to convert an XML file into csv. I have got this below code working to do just that. I however am also trying to include the file name to be part of the extract but I am not able to have that included in this code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in allFiles:
    def iter_docs(cis):
        for docall in cis:
            doc_dict = {}
            for doc in docall:
                tag = [elem.tag for elem in doc]
                txt = [elem.text for elem in doc]
                if len(tag) > 0:
                    doc_dict.update(dict(zip(tag, txt)))
                else:
                    doc_dict[doc.tag] = doc.text
             yield doc_dict
     etree = ET.parse(file)
     df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(list(iter_docs(etree.getroot()))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([file] + list(iter_docs(etree.getroot()))))
```

to get a column with the filename added

By the way, this approach will give you bad performance.

A better approach is to collect the df in a list and convert that to a big one at the end.

```
list_of_df = []

for file in allFiles:
    def iter_docs(cis):

    # your code

    list_of_df.append(pd.DataFrame([file] + list(iter_docs(etree.getroot()))))

# at the end 
df = pd.concat(list_of_df)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I get an error `AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'getroot'` when I try to perform `list_of_df.append(pd.DataFrame([file] + list(iter_docs(etree.getroot()))))`

Comment: does it work without `[file]+`. if it doesn't, the error is somewhere else and it's probably indentation (assuming your own example runs)